# Using a Reaction Collector on a message the bot sent

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Been working on this bot for a bit, but I seem to be stumped. every time I run it, it says

*UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createReactionCollector' of undefined*

This is caused by 
**const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });**
and i dont know how else to do this. Most of the other examples are either outdated or made for a particular purpose, making it hard to implement them into my code. I really appreciate any help you can provide!

```
if (command === 'ping') {
    const pingEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#03cffc')
        .setTitle('Ping!')
        .setDescription(`${message.author.username} is playing a game! \n \n Playing With: \n ` + isPlaying);
    message.channel.send(pingEmbed)
        .then(sentEmbed => {
            sentEmbed.react("")
        }).then( async message => {
            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
            };

            const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

            collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
            });

            collector.on('end', collected => {
                console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
            });
        })}
```

Comment: Is it in the right scope? Is "message" defined?

Comment: `message` is returning undefined

Comment: yes, I get that, the message it's supposed to have the collection is the one it sent. what I need help on is how to set up a reaction collector on a message the bot just sent

Comment: If `message` is already the name of your global emitted message object, don't use the name `message` again, use another name e.g `msg` or `m`

Comment: I just tried that, however, the error still occurs what I need is a way to create a reaction collector on an object the bot just sent, So I don't mind the code being changed, I'm just saying what I've tried.

Comment: cloud you edit with more code that wrap `if (command === 'ping')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use two `then` methods. Simply one would be enough for your case. Instead of having to use another `then` method and passing in `message`, you can just replace `message`  with `sentEmbed`.

Code:

```js
if (command === 'ping') {
    const pingEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#03cffc')
        .setTitle('Ping!')
        .setDescription(`${message.author.username} is playing a game! \n \n Playing With: \n ` + isPlaying);
    message.channel.send(pingEmbed)
        .then(sentEmbed => {
            sentEmbed.react("")
            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
            };

            const collector = sentEmbed.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

            collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
            });

            collector.on('end', collected => {
                console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
            });
        })
}
```